# celery 'Worker-n' pid:xxxx exited with 'exitcode 1' when I import hmmlearn

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, anaconda, conda, hmmlearn

In my tasks.py file, when I import hmmlearn,

```
from hmmlearn import hmm
```

and start my celery workers, I get the following error

```
[2017-06-14 09:18:27,638: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: 
sm.tasks.mytask[4e46806e-6f0f-420f-baac-c727c2a382d4]
[2017-06-14 09:18:27,716: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-4' pid:5264 
exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-06-14 09:18:29,857: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-7' pid:3172 
exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-06-14 09:18:29,857: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-6' pid:5768 
exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-06-14 09:18:29,857: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-5' pid:5236 
exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-06-14 09:18:31,450: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-8' pid:5876 
exited with 'exitcode 1'
```

And after I shutdown the worker,

```
[2017-06-14 09:19:28,545: WARNING/MainProcess] c:\anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\celery\apps\worker.py:161: CDeprecationWarning:
Starting from version 3.2 Celery will refuse to accept pickle by default.
```

If I just comment out that import and code using that import, everything works fine. But, I'm able to execute all the tasks(including the hmm code) as standalone python code on ipython without any issues.

I'm using the conda distribution with following details

```
Current conda install:

           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.21
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.21
conda-build version : 1.21.3
     python version : 3.5.2.final.0
   requests version : 2.14.2

λ conda list | grep celery
celery                    3.1.18                    <pip>

λ conda list | grep kombu
kombu                     3.0.37                    <pip>

λ conda list | grep hmmlearn
hmmlearn                  0.1.1               np111py35_0    omnia
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you resolved this? Seeing the same with pymc3.

Answer (score 3):

This might be because celery 3.1.xx comes bundled with billiard 3.3.

If you upgrade that package (to 3.5 at time of writing), the service might work again.

```
pip install --upgrade billiard
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon a similar situation. Upgrading `billiard` to 3.5, as suggested in a different answer, was not an option (because it conflicts with `Celery==3.1.25` and I prefer that particular version for Windows its support).

I figured out, however, that in my case the problem was most probably due to [this issue](https://github.com/celery/billiard/issues/168) - it occurred only when I tried to import anything from `sklearn` in the Worker's process.

The problem was resolved by adding this snippet *before* the `import`s from `sklearn`:

```
from multiprocessing import current_process
try:
    current_process()._config
except AttributeError:
    current_process()._config = {'semprefix': '/mp'}
```